# How can I change tab border brush on changing key board focus in wpf style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, tabitem

I want to change border color of tab item when it has key board focus. I have written following trigger in its style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}">
 <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#800000" />
        </Trigger>
```

It works fine for all other UI controls except tab itme. Can any one please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is working fine for me (make sure you actually have the keyboard focus to view the change in color)

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

You can also try this to change the color if any item inside the Tab have keyboard focus

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">

                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">

                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```